# Get grandchildren of an object with django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm building a webapp with django with the following models:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    ...

class Branch(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    ...

class Event(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch)
```

My questions is how can I get all events by their business (not their branch), and if it possible to do so in a DB query.

Thanks!

Comment: use django-mptt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django querysets allow you to use the "__" notation to access relationships.  You can take it to any depth and read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships
>   in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind
>   the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related
>   fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get
>   to the field you want.

Any of the following should work in your case:

```
Event.objects.filter(branch__business=<business>)
Event.objects.filter(branch__business_id=<business-id>)
Event.objects.filter(branch__business__id=<business-id>)
# if business had a name field you could also use
Event.objects.filter(branch__business__name=name-of-business)
```